# Create a customised bar graph using SfCartesianChart

Tags: flutter, dart, syncfusion, syncfusion-chart

[image]

I have tried creating this bar graph using `SfCartesianChart`, and have been able to complete 95% of it, but unable to remove the middle labels.

[image]

...

Answer (score -1):

Lobo,

Greetings from Syncfusion.

We have validated your query and we have achieved your requirement by using the [axisLabelFormatter](https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/cartesian-charts/callbacks#axislabelformatter) callback in axis. We have rendered the first and last axis labels alone using this [axisLabelFormatter](https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/cartesian-charts/callbacks#axislabelformatter) callback, and its invoked while rendering each axis label in the chart. Please refer the following code snippet.

Code snippet :

```
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Syncusion flutter charts'),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        body: SfCartesianChart(
          primaryXAxis: CategoryAxis(
            axisLabelFormatter: (AxisLabelRenderDetails details) {
              String text = details.value == 0
                  ? 'Jun 2022'
                  : details.value == chartData.length - 1
                      ? 'Mar 2022'
                      : "";
              return ChartAxisLabel(text, details.textStyle);
            },
            majorGridLines: const MajorGridLines(width: 0),
            majorTickLines: const MajorTickLines(width: 0),
          ),
          primaryYAxis: NumericAxis(
            isVisible: false,
            majorTickLines: const MajorTickLines(width: 0),
            majorGridLines: const MajorGridLines(width: 0),
          ),
          series: <ChartSeries<ChartSampleData, String>>[
            ColumnSeries<ChartSampleData, String>(
                dataSource: chartData,
                dataLabelSettings: const DataLabelSettings(isVisible: true),
                xValueMapper: (ChartSampleData sales, _) => sales.x,
                yValueMapper: (ChartSampleData sales, _) => sales.y),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ChartSampleData {
  ChartSampleData(this.x, this.y);
  final String? x;
  final double? y;
}

final List<ChartSampleData> chartData = [
  ChartSampleData('jan', 50.56),
  ChartSampleData('Feb', 49.42),
  ChartSampleData('Mar', 53.21),
  ChartSampleData('Apr', 64.78),
  ChartSampleData('May', 59.97),
];
```

ScreenShot:
[Syncfusion Custom Axis Label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPaao.png)

Regards,

Lokesh Palani.